# Ruby on Rails devise password override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My existing app uses Devise for user authentication which works fine for my user signup/confirmation process.  Users simply enter an email address, a password, and password_confirmation.  They get the confirmation email and all is good!

Now, I want to allow `account_admins` to have the ability to create additional users that would fall under them.

I have the controller and the form wired up and the user is being created.  However, it occurs to me that I need to allow the account_admin to bypass the `password` and `password_confirmation` fields.  *Otherwise, the account_admin user would need to send a separate email to each user with the password they created for them, which I don't like.*

**Instead, it makes more sense to just have the account_admin fill in the required fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, and `email` to create the user and have Devise create & email a password to the user.**

I've looked at quite a few [Devise resources](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation) and [other things](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Automatically-generate-password-for-users-(simpler-registration)) ppl have done, but most of them have me completely rewiring the confirmation process as well, which I don't want to do.

So, here is my form view `views/users/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_admin_index_path(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :first_name, "First Name", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :email, "Email", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :phone_number, "Phone Number", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :password, "Password", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= link_to "Cancel", "", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

And the associated controller methods `controllers/users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_company_and_locations

  def new
    if current_user.is_account_owner
      @user = User.new
    else
      flash[:danger] = "You do not have permission to do this action!"
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.company_id = current_user.company.id
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "User succesfully created!"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :new
    end
  end



  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

And since I'm also using devise for my `User` model, I needed to add the following to my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users_admin, :controller => 'users'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using devise_invitable?

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

This would let you use your form to create the extra user data, then send an invitation to your new users - the gem itself has a stubbed out email that just has a link to back to the site with a token, that lets them set their password

This isn't a complicated process this way.

## 1 Add the gem to your Gemfile and run bundle install

```
gem 'devise_invitable'
```

## 2 Run the install generator for the initializer

```
rails generate devise_invitable:install
```

## 3 Run the generator for the model

```
rails generate devise_invitable User
```

## 4 Add invitable to your model

```
  # your list of mods might be different, it will depend on what you're using
  devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable , :validatable , :confirmable, :invitable
```

## 5 Create a migration to add invitation fields

```
rails g migration add_invitable_to_user
```

Open the migration and add this to it

```
def change
    add_column :users, :invitation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :invitation_created_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :invitation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :invitation_accepted_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :invitation_limit, :integer
    add_column :users, :invited_by_id, :integer
    add_column :users, :invited_by_type, :string
    add_index :users, :invitation_token, :unique => true

    # Allow null encrypted_password
    change_column_null :users, :encrypted_password, :string, true
    # Allow null password_salt (add it if you are using Devise's encryptable module)
    change_column_null :users, :password_salt, :string, true
end
```

## 6 Generate the views so you can edit your invitation pages

```
rails generate devise_invitable:views
```

## 7 Add a route for devise invitations

```
# you might have other controllers or put them in a different directory, but it will be similar to this
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations' }
```

## 8 Add the invitation controller

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  protected

  def invite_params
    params.permit(user: [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :invitation_token, :provider, :skip_invitation])
  end

  def accept_invitation_params
    params.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number )
  end

end
```

## 9 Change the form to invite

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_invitation_path(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :first_name, "First Name", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :email, "Email", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :phone_number, "Phone Number", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :password, "Password", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation", class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", :required => true, required: "" %>

   <%= link_to "Cancel", "", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't even know it existed.  Let me try it out!

Comment: Looks like this will work.  Been working on some heavy customization though.